# Specflow test on login

Tags: asp.net, selenium, forms-authentication, specflow

I have a Specflow/Gherkin test to test an Asp.net application that involves logging into to perform an action using Selenium (and FireFox). Above my controller action I have the [Authorize] token and the site performs as I expect when manually testing. My login uses Forms Authentication. 
My test goes as follows:

1. Navigate to Login page
2. Provide user and password
3. Click Login
4. Navigate to Create Product page (must be logged in)
5. Enter product detail
6. Save button
7. Check item is in database

What looks to be happening is steps 1-3 are fine. But when I execute Step 4, it is redirecting to the login page again. So Step 5 fails, as that isn't the page that is expected. 
If I Start at Step 3 and login on the redirect, it works fine e.g.:

1. Navigate to Create Product page
2. Provide user and password
3. Click Login
4. Enter product detail
5. Save button
6. Check item is in database

Is there something specific I need to add to Selenium to make it save the session/login token?

Answer (score 0):

When we're writing a BDD test either with Specflow, Cucumber or any other tool, we need to center our focus on what the end user needs to do to get the scenario done, in other words: the "As a user" perspective.

So in your scenario, as a user if he needs to navigate to loginPage, login and then navigate to createProductPage and login again, so be it! If that's true, write steps that would login again. 
If not, on the other hand, if the user needs to login one single time, you don't need to store a session or anything else, I think in this case you have a bug in your application.

PS: if that wont work you can store a profile of your browser with the authentication token and use it, because when a browser gets instantiated it gets a clean browser profile.

Comment: I'll concede there is a bug in my application then, as I don't think logging in twice makes a good experience. But as I say, it works if I do the same "test" manually.

Answer (score 0):

OK so it transpires that the transition between steps 3 and 4 are happening too quick. So once I Login, i should verify the page title for example (as it redirects back to the Home page) and then proceed to the Create. Step 4 happens too quick to save the cookie/session.